# 2D array Classification using Python

Tags: python, arrays, classification, voice-recognition, mfcc

I am trying to build a voice recognition application. Until now, I already extract the mfcc feature from 10 sample voice. Each sample yield different shape like shown below:

(698, 12)

(414, 12)

(610, 12)

(586, 12)

(698, 12)

(282, 12)

(250, 12)

(370, 12)

(694, 12)

(490, 12)

I planned to use kNN (or other classification algorithms) to do this but the shapes are not same for every sample and it 2D array not 1D array so I can feed it directly to the model.

How can I convert this array such a way so I can feed it into machine learning algorithm or how to build a model using 2D array?

Please advise

Comment: What does the first dimension of your data specifies? What is it?

Comment: What is the desired data type or dimension for your functions? `(n, 2)` of integers? Have already tried to code your algorithm or do you use an existing package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I complete this using GMM. So each observation will have its own model.